# Boss who is doing an executive MBA handing over all assignments to a graduate trainee

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

My friend's company offers an MBA degree to executives, the program is from one of the top business schools. Her boss is enrolled in the program.

He gives her all his assignments and projects, including the group ones to carry out, she can't outright ask him to stop because he is in a significant position of power in the industry itself.

She doesn't like doing this work because she has no prior experience in these projects and her workday is 10 hours excluding her boss' assignments.

What course of action can she take to handle this situation effectively?

Comment: Do you think she should leak this to the heads of the company?

Comment: Also, does your friend have a contract with a listed number of hours? This might be solved with something as simple as "Sure, but I'm already working a full load; which of my normal scheduled tasks shall I drop to do your homework?"

Comment: @vai shn I enjoy the irony of your "friend" having an issue doing her boss's assignments, while she has asked *you* to post this question here instead of doing so herself.

Comment: @MaskedMan She doesn't know I asked the question though :)

Comment: @vaishn Are you trying to get your friend fired, or at least in some sort of trouble? What if her boss reads this post? If she has shared her issue with you privately, you should not share it with the internet without her consent.

Comment: @MaskedMan No, does it seem obvious who I am talking about?

Comment: @vaishn *If* I were the boss, it would be obvious to me who you are talking about, don't you think? Uhm, actually, can you tell if I am her boss?

Comment: @MaskedMan you're implying there aren't thousands of bosses around the globe who are lazily offloading their homework onto their employees at this very moment.

Comment: @Erik The thousands of bosses around the globe don't really matter here. The OP has specified her location and his/her "friend" is likely to be from the same location. Then there are sufficient details to pinpoint it to a reasonable number. Anyway, that is not even relevant. The goal here is not whether *we* can find out who the OP's friend is, but whether the *boss* can find out if the post is talking about him. Moreover, *any* such lazy boss might assume that it is referring to him, even if he is not the OP's "friend"'s boss.

Comment: I don't think we can hold the asker accountable for another person being unreasonable. It becomes impossible to ask any sensitive questions otherwise; an unreasonable person can take anything and make an issue out of it.

Comment: Actually we don't stay in the same place, its a far stretch to connect the dots

Answer (score 7):

Start by quietly asking around and see if this is normal practice for the other executives in the company.  If so, ask how they coped with the situation.

If this doesn't result in any feedback, ask whoever administers the MBA course for your company.

I'm guessing that there's someone at your company who arranges the courses for the executives, so I'd raise this question with them:

> My manager is enrolled in this MBA course and she's asking me to write these assignments, what should I do?

This can go one of two ways:

1. Your friend could get fired for refusing to do the assignments (or for getting the manager into trouble)
2. Your friend could just carry on doing the assignments and let her manager "earn" his degree

Although the second option is pretty demeaning (and unethical), there's the bonus that your friend will learn everything required for the degree course and be in a position to take the course his/herself and move on to a better job.

Comment: Her friend could make some "easy" mistakes. The executive will soon learn that it is not smart to let someone else try to earn his degree ;)

Comment: *she has no prior experience in these projects and her workday is 10 hours excluding her boss' assignments.*. With that workload, she probably don't even need to make mistakes on purpose.

Comment: Just wait until her boss runs into the capstone project having learned nothing.

Answer (score 4):

> What course of action can she take to handle this situation effectively?

I would definitely *not* recommend to purposely do a bad/low quality job (as suggested by some comment), as this can have negative consequences for the OP, like a tarnished reputation, possible lay-off or maybe even lawsuits.

It seems like this situation is no good for your friend. If you say she really doesn't like that work then she would probably be better finding a job where this does not happen.

She can also try speak to her boss, and explain him the situation, and that the additional assignments and projects given to her are taking a toll on her productivity and other tasks.

However, this can only end in two ways, and considering how you describe this boss it seems that he would most surely ignore her request. Still, it is worth a shot asking him, there is a chance he changes his mind.

She can also try escalate the situation, and go over her boss' head, but I am not sure if this will accomplish anything; procede at your own risk. Anyways, it would probably be wiser to update her CV and start looking for a new job.

Comment: He is a VP of the company, there is no one to go over him to.

Comment: Possible lawsuits? "Yes, your honor, my employee purposefully made mistakes on my MBA assignment." I can't think of a reason something like this would go to court.  Being fired and having a tarnished reputation might happen though.

Comment: @Ramhound you may be right, it could not reach court. But it will definitely have some fallout on the Friend doing so

Answer (score 0):

Speak to the university/business school that is doing the MBA and start the dicussion about plagiarism. The boss is gaining credit off of someone else's work, that's plagiarism in a nut shell.

Your friend should contact the university and ask to put in an anomynous feedback that the work submitted by her boss is plagarised and provide evidence. Then the university can handle the process and leave your friend in the clear.

This will not put your friend in the best books, as they could be considered a suspect, however proving such a thing would be difficult. But your boss gaining a free education is a terrible thing and should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential things that your friend should look into in order to fix this.

First and most importantly, she needs to look up the school and local laws regarding plagiarism, because there is a chance that not only her boss is breaking the law by using someone else's work, there is also a chance that **she herself** is breaking the law by helping someone else cheat their way through an education.

If it's the first, it'd be nice of her to mention this to her boss, but if it's the latter that's a very clear reason for her to stop doing his assignments. There's not an awful lot of arguing that can be done against "I'm not doing these assignments, that's illegal and I could get in trouble". (And most consequences would end in a lawsuit, which your friend would likely win)

If it isn't illegal for her to do it, and her boss still wants her to do it, then probably there isn't much she can do. At this point, it becomes a question of priorities.

So she should ask "Which of my normal tasks does this replace? I'll need about [x] hours a week to do your assignments, so please let me know which other tasks I can drop."

I'm assuming she has some kind of contract outlining how many hours a week she has to work, or that there is some kind of overtime comp, so there should be no reason why being given more work requires her to work longer days. It's her boss' job to prioritize the work that needs to be done.